# What are examples of operators showing that convergence in the strong operator topology doesn't behave well?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Precisely, given an example of nets of operators $(T_\lambda) , (S_\lambda) \in \mathcal{B} (\mathcal{H}) $, $\mathcal{H} $ being a Hilbert space, converging respectively to $T, S $ in the strong operator topology, but the net $(T_\lambda S_\lambda) $ does not converge to $TS$ (in the same topology of course)

Comment: I see that the other question is related, but I think it is interesting if we look at all examples where this is realized, or how to cook them.

Comment: What do you mean all examples? There are probably infinitely many examples

Comment: I meant can't we classify them or characterize them?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean classify them or characterize them